# How to select a row and update postgresql table in node js API

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am working with email verification. I have managed to send email which contains a link with unique token. Now I want to update the users table when user click on the link which is sent them by email. I have the following piece of code:

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    verified = 1;
    oldToken = req.query.token;
    newToken = null;

    const retrieveToken = await pool.query("SELECT token FROM users WHERE token = $1;", [req.query.token])
    if (retrieveToken.rows.length < 1){
      return res.send({ message:  "invalid token" });
      //return res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      const verifyUser = await pool.query("UPDATE users SET verified=$1, token=$2 WHERE token=$3", [verified, newToken, req.query.token])
      return res.send({message: "Accound has been verified"})
    }
})
```

When I test this code from postman it always executes **if block** and return "invalid token". It never goes inside of **else block** though the token exists in the table. I have executed the select query with a valid token in the PostgreSQL terminal and it returns a row. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem here and what is the solution?

Cheers

Comment: The SELECT seems useless to me to begin with. Just run the UPDATE, then check the number of affected rows. If it's zero, the token did no exist.

Comment: I just executed the following code but it doesn't update the table:
`
const verifyUser = await pool.query("UPDATE users SET verified=$1, token=$2 WHERE token=$3", [verified, newToken, req.query.token])
  if (verifyUser)
  {
    return res.send({message: "This email is verified now"})
  }
`